# What follows "on the same page"

Tags: word-choice, idioms, prepositions

I would like to continue the sentence with the idea that we will work tuned in. Is it...?

> we need to be sure that we are in the same page **for** this work
>
> we need to be sure that we are in the same page **to** this work
>
> we need to be sure that we are in the same page **in** this work

or any other correct ussage

It just seems to me that none of them is right, and I would like to know how that expression is used

Comment: The idiom is "***on*** the same page".

Comment: you said it in your 1st sentence:  **all in tune**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preposition *in* works best here.

"… we are on the same page **in** this"

You could also say,
"… we are on the same page **regarding** this work"

HTH.

Comment: are the other preposition wrong? is it a matter of language usage or the other preposition won't mean anything if I use them in that context?

Answer (score -2):

> Okay, I think we are **reading from the same page** now. We can
>   discuss the future of this project more productively.

[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/page)